# Overlayfs working dir

Tags: overlayfs

on an Ubuntu (16.04 LTS) working as Webserver I have installed overlayfs (I did already some months ago on another machine).
On both machine I have:

```
overlayroot="tmpfs:swap=1,recurse=0"
```

But on the new one, boot fails with

```
overlayfs: missing working dir
```

How do I set the working dir parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hopelessly late I know, but just in case someone else should wonder - workdir should be set for you by `/usr/share/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/overlayroot`. Maybe you need to regenerate your initramfs?

The default is `/media/root-rw/overlay-workdir/_` and you can set it manually by adding `workdir=...` as an option to the overlayfs mount command/fstab entry.